# Ubuntu 14 install phpize 7.2

Tags: php, ubuntu

Как установить phpize7.2 на ubuntu 14.04.5?

Репозиторий добавлен:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
Пакеты обновлены:
sudo apt-get update

Не находит пакет:
sudo apt install php7.2-dev
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет php7.2-dev
E: Не удалось найти пакет по регулярному выражению «php7.2-dev»

Comment: А вы читали в репозитории, что минимальная версия Ubuntu 16.04? Конечно у вас ничего не поставится.

Answer (score 0):

Если это не работает, попробуйте заставить его вот так:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev  -y --all-not authenticated
```

Так как вы принудительно установите неаутентифицированные пакеты